# How to give the party a reason to work together without hard railroading?

Tags: dnd-5e, party

This is my first real attempt at DMing, so the lack of ideas might just be normal, but I thought I'd ask anyway.
To be clear: the party *is* working together now, but I would love to find a way to make them *want* to work together later (they will probably do it even without a reason, because "we're all sitting at the same table" but I'd like to make it a little more "real").

In the campaign the four adventurers were, each one for their own reason linked to their background, sent to find an artifact that was stolen. The mission was harder than expected, but this made them noticeable to the eyes of an Anglerlich, a powerful monster who eats heroism and is planning to "grow" them and eat them when they're stronger. For this reason it created a "bait", an illusory evil guy, that is messing with them and stole some of their preciouses. This really railroaded their path: if they want to recover their stuff they have to work together and all go where the "bait" told them to go.
Now, after this quest I was planning to "keep the promises" and give them their stuff back, making them think that the worst is over, only to strike stronger later.

So now I want to give them some space, some liberty, but I'd really love them to form an actual party, not linked by obligation but by something else that makes them want to go on adventures together. I can't really think of anything beside "you're now a team of the Adventurers' Guild and you work together" and I might just go for it, but I'd appreciate other ideas.